# Weak * convergence in $\ell^{\infty}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, weak-convergence, weak-topology, weak-lp-spaces

Let $x=(x_1, x_2, \cdots) \in \ell^{\infty} = (\ell^1)^*$.

Let $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x_k e_k$ be the $n$-th partial sum.

(1) Show that $s_n \stackrel{\ast}{\rightharpoonup}x$ (i.e. show the the weak $^*$ convergence).

(2) Does the net $s_F= \sum_{k\in F} x_k e_k$ of finite partial sums converge int the weak$^*$ topology to $x$?

Things I know:

For (1):

We have that $\ell^1 = c_0^*$.

Since $(e_n) \subset \ell^1$, $(e_n)$ converges to $0$ in the weak $^*$ topology.

Since $s_n$ is finite, we know that each $s_n \in \ell^1.$.

So we want to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n= x$.

But this above seems obvious. I'm sure I missed something important here, since I haven't really used the the definitions of $\ell^1$ and $\ell^{\infty}$...

So please let me know how to proceed from here.

For (2),

I'm not sure about this one. My guess is yes. But I don't have any clues on how to prove that.

Any help is appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(y_k) \in \ell^{1}$. Then $s_n((y_k))= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}x_ky_k \to \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}x_ky_k$, Note that the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}x_ky_k$ converges absolutely. This proves the first part. The second part follows from the fact that for any $\epsilon >0$ we can find $N$ with $\sum\limits_{k=N}^{\infty}|x_k||y_k| <\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Just wondering why the above proves the first part. Don't we have $s_n= \sum_{k=1}^n x_k e_k$. Where did the $(e_k)$ go?

Comment: Also, for (2), does the "fact" follow from (1)?

Comment: @Rye An element $s_k$ acts on an elmenet $(y_i)$ of $\ell^{1}$ by the formula $s_k (y_i)= \sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} x_iy_i$. When we arite $\ell^{*}$ as $(\ell^{1})^{*}$ we use this identification.

Comment: @Rye The 'fact' I used for second part is a basic  fact about convergence of  series.

Comment: For (2), which convergence of series are you assuming? Thanks!

Comment: @Rye If $(x_i)$ is a bounded sequence and $(y_i) \in \ell^{1}$ then the series $\sum x_iy_i$ is absoluetly convergent.